# How do I get jQuery to re-render a partial from Ruby and then place it in a div?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a button which looks like this:

```
<%= link_to "Join", "#", :id => "joinleave", :class => "buttonrefresh small join button expand", :'project-id' => @project.id %>
```

I then have jQuery called when it gets clicked. It changes the text in the button and the button function and all that, but I then need it to re-render a partial from Ruby into a `<div>`.

```
<div class="content" id="peoplerender" data-section-content>
  <%= render 'people' %>
</div>
```

The .js is in "assets/javascript" and the view is in "apps/views/projects".  The partials are also in the same folder and work fine when the page loads. I just need it to update when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery, you have its AJAX return update `$(".content")` like so :

**Your controller**

```
def show

  @people = whatever_people_logic_you_already_have

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json do
      render :json => @people.to_json, :layout => false
    end
  end
end
```

**Your AJAX** :

```
$.ajax({
   url: your_url_to_your_show,
   type: 'get',
   success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     $(".content").html(data);
   }
});
```

I'm assuming your controllers are sending back the proper information. Use the `console.log` to identify what that is.

Comment: what would I put under data?  There aren't any parameters I need to pass.

Comment: Oh ok, is it just a `get` request then? In that change `type` to `get` and remove `data`.

Comment: I just tried that and still nothing.  So now it looks like this.

Comment: $.ajax({
   url: "/app/views/projects/_people.html.erb",
   type: 'get',
   success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $("#peoplerender").html(data);
   }
});

Comment: Ah ok you're making the call to your partial. It should be made to your controller action that would give you the dynamic data that would populate _people.html.erb. But question, is there any dynamic data in there or is just static details that wouldn't change whether or not the button is clicked? If thats the case, why not just do a hide/show on .content ?

Comment: It's calling new information from the database (the button either adds or removes a user and the partial will then add that user to list since it's added to the DB).  I don't know how I would add it to the controller, or what I would even add.  Would I have to add a new def?

Comment: Does the back end functionality work even without the partial updating? Meaning does a signal go somehow to the database and update something accordingly? If so, what controller is it touching? And how are you touching that in your original request?

Comment: This is the code in the view '<section><p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel4">people</a></p><div class="content" id="peoplerender" data-section-content><%= render 'people' %></div></section>'  It renders it correctly when the page is loaded, I just need it to render again.

Comment: Ah ok I understand. What action is this loading in your controller? Is this page the `index`, the `show` page? Is it something custom? Basically, where is it finding the appropriately information to populate your people partial with? We'll need to make sure that that controller is returning the right infos, or we'll make a new action to exclusively send info back for this purpose.

Comment: It's being rendered in the show page so its under the projects controller def show.

Comment: Ok awesome, so your ajax request should not be the url of the partial. It should be the url of the page your on. And in your controller, you want to have a `respond_to` that returns json alongside your already working `html` return. In this way, the json one will become your `data` in your ajax success return. Does that make sense? I'll write some code later.

Comment: Oh no no that makes sense.  I can do that.  Thank you!

Comment: Feel free to give me up an upvote and accepted answer if this works for you.